# net/http GET request error tls oversized record received with length 20527

Tags: networking, go, https, get, network-programming

I'm stucking  to perform a get request using Golang and I also have tried three distinct implementations without success. For all them I'm receiving this error message:

**Get https://11.11.11.1:0000/httpgw.conf?Type=SMS&Address=12345678&MsgID=12
3&Notify=N&Validity=24:00&OAdC=15555&Message=HelloBrother: tls: oversized recor
d received with length 20527**

Bellow is the entire source code that I'm working on:

```
    package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    cmdSecSMS := "https://11.11.11.1:0000/httpgw.conf?Type=SMS&Address=12345678&MsgID=123&Notify=N&Validity=24:00&OAdC=15555&Message="
    msg := "HelloBrother"
    cmdSecUrlSMS := cmdSecSMS + msg

    doClientTrans(cmdSecUrlSMS)

    doGetClient(cmdSecUrlSMS)

    doGet(cmdSecUrlSMS)
}

func doClientTrans(address string) {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    response, err := client.Get(address)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(contents))
        fmt.Println(" Size: ", len(string(contents)), " url: ", address)
        fmt.Println(" Status Code:  ", response.StatusCode)
        hdr := response.Header
        for key, value := range hdr {
            fmt.Println(" ", key, ":", value)
        }
    }
}

func doGet(url string) {
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Println(" Size: ", len(string(contents)), " url: ", url)
        fmt.Println(" Status Code:  ", response.StatusCode)
        hdr := response.Header
        for key, value := range hdr {
            fmt.Println(" ", key, ":", value)
        }
    }
}

func doGetClient(url string) {
    client := &http.Client{}

    response, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Println(" Size: ", len(string(contents)), " url: ", url)
        fmt.Println(" Status Code: ", response.StatusCode)
        hdr := response.Header
        for key, value := range hdr {
            fmt.Println(" ", key, ":", value)
        }
    }
}
```

When using telnet, this GET request works normally:

telnet 11.11.11.1 0000

Get https://11.11.11.1:0000/httpgw.conf?Type=SMS&Address=12345678&MsgID=12
3&Notify=N&Validity=24:00&OAdC=15555&Message=HelloBrother HTTP/1.1

^:
exit

[image]

I'm running the golang app in the windows server 2012 and I don't know nothing about the server tech stack.

It's possible to fix this issue? There is a configuration workaround or something else that I can try?

thanks for your help

Comment: if you can use telnet, it's not HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to share with you that I reach the needed implementation.

The code bellow works!

Thanks for your comments that guide me to the right approach for this task:

```
package main


import (
 "bufio"
 "crypto/tls"
 "fmt"
 "io/ioutil"
 "net"
 "net/http"
 "os"
)


func main() {


 cmdSecSMS := "GET https://10.xxx.xx.x:xx43/httpgw.conf?" +
 "Type=SMS&Address=5511111&MsgID=123&Notify=N&Validity=24:00&OAdC=15555&" +
 "Message=blablah " +
 "HTTP/1.1"


 fmt.Println(cmdSecSMS)
 cmdSecUrlSMS := cmdSecSMS
 hostName := "10.xxx.xx.x"
 portNum := "xx43"

 doDial(cmdSecUrlSMS, hostName, portNum)

 //doClientTrans(cmdSecUrlSMS)

 //doGetClient(cmdSecUrlSMS)

 //doGet(cmdSecUrlSMS)

}


func doDial(cmd, host, port string) {
 // connect to this socket
 conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port)


 if err != nil {
 fmt.Printf("Some error %v", err)
 return
 } else {
 defer conn.Close()
 fmt.Printf("Connection established between %s and localhost.\n", host)
 fmt.Printf("Local Address : %s \n", conn.LocalAddr().String())
 fmt.Printf("Remote Address : %s \n", conn.RemoteAddr().String())


 // send to socket
 fmt.Fprintf(conn, cmd+"\n")
 // listen for reply
 message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
 fmt.Print("Message from server: " + message)
 }
```

}

Thank you guys for your support!